# Improve This Nested Set "Full Path" SQL Statement - Doesn't Return All Records

Tags: sql

I'm currently using Access and connecting to a MySQL database using ODBC linked tables. This is a recipe database concept that may eventually go live. We're storing "labels" using the nested set model and then linking them to the recipes using a junction table. I've written a SQL statement that shows the full path for all assigned labels for a given recipe. However, it does show labels that are only 2 levels deep because of the logic in the statement. Can this be improved? Can it be done in MySQL but not in Access? I know I'm already using some Access-only code in the selection of fields where I used the IIF statement to do a basic comparison.

```
SELECT recipelabel.labelid, parent1.lbltext+' > '+IIf(parent2.lbltext<>node.lblText,parent2.lbltext+' > ','')+IIf(parent3.lbltext<>node.lblText,parent3.lbltext+' > ','')+node.lbltext AS LabelPath
FROM labels AS parent1, labels AS parent2, labels AS parent3, recipelabel INNER JOIN labels AS node ON recipelabel.labelid=node.id
WHERE node.lft Between parent1.lft And parent1.rgt And node.lft Between parent2.lft And parent2.rgt And node.lft Between parent3.lft And parent3.rgt And parent1.nodelevel=1 And parent2.nodelevel=2 And parent3.nodelevel=3 And recipelabel.recipeid=4;
```

This returns the following:

```
Course > Breads > Buns
Ingredients > Fruit > Berries > Raspberries
```

It should return the following:

```
Course > Breads > Buns
Cuisine > German
Event/Occasion > Breakfast
Ingredients > Fruit > Berries > Raspberries
```

Basically the only solution I've come up with is to force all labels to be no more than 3 levels deep and to force the user to always assign a label that is at least 2 levels deep. Is there a solution using SQL that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I failed to mention that I ventured somewhat outside of the traditional nested set model by storing the node level in the database. This query is only possible because of that unless you have another way that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your join expressions to join Clause and do a left join

E.g.

```
FROM 
    labels AS parent1, 
    labels AS parent2, 
    recipelabel 
    INNER JOIN labels AS node 
    ON recipelabel.labelid=node.id
    LEFT JOIN labels AS parent3 
    ON node.lft Between parent3.lft And parent3.rgt 
         And parent3.nodelevel=3
```

**UPDATE** I missed a join condition  `And parent3.nodelevel=3`

You could keep it in the Where if you want but then you'll have to change it to

```
 And (parent3.nodelevel=3 
    or  parent3.nodelevel is null)
```

I've tested this on other DBs and it works (don't have MYSQL where I am)
However this is supported by the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

specifically

> join_condition:
>
> ```
> ON conditional_expr   | USING (column_list).
> ```

and

> The conditional_expr used with ON is
>   any conditional expression of the form
>   that can be used in a WHERE clause.
>   Generally, you should use the ON
>   clause for conditions that specify how
>   to join tables, and the WHERE clause
>   to restrict which rows you want in the
>   result set.

Comment: I get an error. Here's the exact error message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'recipelabel.labelid=node.id LEFT JOIN labels AS parent3 ON node.lft BETWEEN parent3.lf'.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if it works to use a BETWEEN clause inside a JOIN clause. I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: OK it does work in Toad except that it returns only two of the four records, just like my code above. My Select clause above doesn't work because it contains Access concatenation.

Comment: Statement I'm currently trying: SELECT recipelabel.labelid, parent1.lbltext, node.lbltext AS LabelPath
FROM 
    labels AS parent1, 
    labels AS parent2, 
    recipelabel 
    INNER JOIN labels AS node 
    ON recipelabel.labelid=node.id
    LEFT JOIN labels AS parent3 
    ON node.lft Between parent3.lft And parent3.rgt 
WHERE node.lft Between parent1.lft And parent1.rgt 
  And node.lft Between parent2.lft And parent2.rgt 
  And node.lft Between parent3.lft And parent3.rgt 
  And parent1.nodelevel=1 And parent2.nodelevel=2 
  And parent3.nodelevel=3 And recipelabel.recipeid=4;

Comment: @HK1 Missed the `and parent3.nodelevel=3 ` this turned it back into an INNER JOIN. I've updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: It's still returning only two out of 4 records. But I think the problem is in my where clause: 'AND parent3.nodelevel=3'. Some of these records are only two deep. Using your FROM clause, do I need to change some of my WHERE clause?

Comment: I think I might be getting it. Will post back.

Comment: @Conrad Looks like I got it working using: FROM 
    labels AS parent1, 
    labels AS parent2, 
    recipelabel 
    INNER JOIN labels AS node 
    ON recipelabel.labelid=node.id
    LEFT JOIN labels AS parent3 
    ON node.lft Between parent3.lft And parent3.rgt 
         And parent3.nodelevel=3
WHERE node.lft Between parent1.lft And parent1.rgt 
  And node.lft Between parent2.lft And parent2.rgt 
  And parent1.nodelevel=1 And parent2.nodelevel=2
  And recipelabel.recipeid=4

Comment: I failed to mention that I only have it working in Toad/MySQL, not in MS Access. Appears that Jet/ODBC doesn't like the query and/or the syntax. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @HK1 MS Access uses a lot of parens in its Joins. You might want to start with a simple query in the designer to get that bit right first and then add in the stuff you need.

Comment: I did find a really great, novel solution. I created a view in MySQL which is what I'm using as the backend and I linked to it as a ODBC linked table so I'm getting exactly what I wanted in MS Access. :)